# Mysql GROUP_CONCAT json_object FROM 2 SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have 2 select which, taken individually, works well

**1° SELECT**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( json_object(
'Title', Title, 'Note', Note
) ) AS Event
FROM (
SELECT
CASE WHEN tb_odl.id <> '44'
AND tb_odl.id <> '64'
THEN Odl_Desc
END AS Title,
CASE WHEN tb_odl.id <> '44'
AND tb_odl.id <> '64'
THEN calendar.Notes
END AS Note
FROM calendar
INNER JOIN tb_odl ON calendar.id_odl = tb_odl.id
INNER JOIN tb_user ON calendar.id_user = tb_user.id
WHERE WEEK( calendar.start, 1 ) = 19
AND YEAR( calendar.start ) =2021
)y
```

**2° SELECT**

```
SELECT group_concat(json_object('rep',rep,'temp',temp,'notte',notte)) as opt 
from (
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN tb_odl.id='44' THEN
        "yes" 
    ELSE
        "no" 
    END as rep,
    CASE WHEN tb_odl.id='64' THEN
        "yes" 
    ELSE
        "no" 
    END as temp,
    CASE WHEN tb_odl.Icona='far fa-moon' THEN
        "yes" 
    ELSE
        "no" 
    END as notte    
FROM calendar
INNER JOIN tb_odl
ON calendar.id_odl = tb_odl.id
INNER JOIN tb_user
ON calendar.id_user = tb_user.id
WHERE WEEK(calendar.start,1) = 18 AND YEAR(calendar.start) = 2021)z
```

Now I would like to merge the 2 selects into a new Json

```
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( json_object('Event', Event, 'opt', opt)) AS Pippo 
    FROM(
       *SELECT1*, *SELECT2*)qr
```

What can I use to merge the 2 selects considering that they don't have the same records or the same fields?

I hope I have understood correctly. maybe you meant to do something like that?

```
    SELECT "1" as idrow,y.event,z.opt FORM CALENDAR 
    INNER JOIN(  
      SELECT "1" as idrow, GROUP_CONCAT( json_object('Title', Title, 'Note', Note)) AS Event FROM 
      (SELECT
       CASE WHEN tb_odl.id <> '44' AND tb_odl.id <> '64' THEN 
          Odl_Desc
       END AS Title,
       CASE WHEN tb_odl.id <> '44' AND tb_odl.id <> '64' THEN 
         calendar.Notes
       END AS Note
       FROM calendar
       INNER JOIN tb_odl ON calendar.id_odl = tb_odl.id
       INNER JOIN tb_user ON calendar.id_user = tb_user.id
       WHERE WEEK( calendar.start, 1 ) = 19
       AND YEAR( calendar.start ) =2021
       )y ON y.idrow = idrow                
    INNER JOIN(
      SELECT "1" as idrow, group_concat(json_object('rep',rep,'temp',temp,'notte',notte)) as opt from 
       (SELECT 
        CASE WHEN tb_odl.id='44' THEN
            "yes" 
        ELSE
            "no" 
        END as rep,
        CASE WHEN tb_odl.id='64' THEN
            "yes" 
        ELSE
            "no" 
        END as temp,
        CASE WHEN tb_odl.Icona='far fa-moon' THEN
            "yes" 
        ELSE
            "no" 
        END as notte    
       FROM calendar
       INNER JOIN tb_odl
       ON calendar.id_odl = tb_odl.id
       INNER JOIN tb_user
       ON calendar.id_user = tb_user.id
       WHERE WEEK(calendar.start,1) = 18 AND YEAR(calendar.start) = 2021
       )z ON z.idrow = idrow      
WHERE WEEK(calendar.start,1) = 18 AND YEAR(calendar.start) = 2021
```

Comment: I am quite usure, whyt you get from your SELECt izt shoub be a bunch of rows, with comma seperated jsons, if that is true add a rownumber join the bith table by thier row number

Comment: can you give me an example please

Comment: For example SELECT  "1" as idrow,  Add idrow in the 2 subqueries

Comment: have you mysql 8 or an older Version

Comment: I have MySQL 5.7

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b3def0eed6afe83038b8475889431a47  this will not your problem completly as you need to define an order for bith query, so that the "right" rows are connected.

Comment: but the result is necessarily right lines, as I extrapolate 1 json in the 1st query and 1json in the second query so he as the final record should have a father json record if I'm not mistaken

Comment: see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=609e0c8c690eba4e2d57717799488c75  and from there build your json

Comment: OK THANKS, seems to be working fine THANK YUO